# Error in .M.kind(x) : not yet implemented for matrix with typeof character

Tags: r

I was building documenttermmatrix by R using "tidytext" packages. An error occurred as

> "Error in .M.kind(x) : not yet implemented for matrix with typeof
>   character"

when I executed codes as below:

```
library(tidytext)
dtm <- cast_dtm(doc_term_count, no, presidenttw, words, n)
```

The code works fine when I remove the variable "presidenttw" but I would like to keep this variable for further analysis in the later stage.

The following shows the structure of each variable:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1054900 obs. of  4 variables:
$ no         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ presidenttw: chr  "Chen" "Chen" "Chen" "Chen" ...
$ words      : chr  "" "一日" "一再" "一延" ...
$ n          : int  1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I turned the variable "presidenttw" into factor instead of character to prevent the co-existence of two character variables but the error still occurs. Wonder if there's any way I can keep the variable "presidenttw" while still be able to execute the cast_dtm().

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread perfect for the same problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

docs <- data_frame(doc_id = c("sub001.pdf", "sub002.pdf"),
                   text = c("Tidytext is a beautiful package for text analysis in R. However, I cannot create a Term Document Matrix. I get the following error: “Error in .M.kind(x) : not yet implemented for matrix with typeof NULL”.",
                            "Because I could not stop for Death he kindly stopped for me."))

data(stop_words)

tidy_docs <- docs %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
    anti_join(stop_words) 
#> Joining, by = "word"

tidy_docs
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>    doc_id     word       
#>    <chr>      <chr>      
#>  1 sub001.pdf tidytext   
#>  2 sub001.pdf beautiful  
#>  3 sub001.pdf package    
#>  4 sub001.pdf text       
#>  5 sub001.pdf analysis   
#>  6 sub001.pdf create     
#>  7 sub001.pdf term       
#>  8 sub001.pdf document   
#>  9 sub001.pdf matrix     
#> 10 sub001.pdf error      
#> 11 sub001.pdf error      
#> 12 sub001.pdf m.kind     
#> 13 sub001.pdf implemented
#> 14 sub001.pdf matrix     
#> 15 sub001.pdf typeof     
#> 16 sub001.pdf null       
#> 17 sub002.pdf stop       
#> 18 sub002.pdf death      
#> 19 sub002.pdf kindly     
#> 20 sub002.pdf stopped

tidy_docs %>%
    count(doc_id, word) %>%
    cast_tdm(word, doc_id, n)
#> <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 18, documents: 2)>>
#> Non-/sparse entries: 18/18
#> Sparsity           : 50%
#> Maximal term length: 11
#> Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/issues/126